# How to make the Text field change automatically when a specific Picker value is selected

Tags: swift, swiftui

Please tell me how to make it so that when a certain value is selected from the Picker field, the result in the Text field automatically changes. I wrote the code, but it gives an error Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012"]
    @State private var selectedYearIndex = 2
    @State private var resultText = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch selectedYearIndex {
        case 0:
            self.resultText = "Hello"
        case 1:
            self.resultText = "Hi"
        case 2:
            self.resultText = "Bye"
        default:
            self.resultText = "No"
        }
        
        VStack {
            Text("Result Text:")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(resultText)")
            Spacer()
            
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                
                ForEach(0..<years.count) {
                    Text("\(years[$0])").font(.title)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your switch should be inside a function and not with your view code to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`onChange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)), it's exactly what it was created for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012"]
    @State private var selectedYearIndex = 2
    @State private var resultText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Result Text:")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(resultText)")
            Spacer()
            
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                
                ForEach(0..<years.count) {
                    Text("\(years[$0])").font(.title)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedYearIndex) { index in // <-- what changed
                switch index { // <-- what to do when it changed
                case 0:
                    resultText = "Hello"
                case 1:
                    resultText = "Hi"
                case 2:
                    resultText = "Bye"
                default:
                    resultText = "No"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can also move the logic to a separate function:

```
// ...
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                
                ForEach(0..<years.count) {
                    Text("\(years[$0])").font(.title)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedYearIndex, perform: onChangeOfPicker)
        }
    }
    
    func onChangeOfPicker(index: Int) {
        switch index {
        case 0:
            resultText = "Hello"
        case 1:
            resultText = "Hi"
        case 2:
            resultText = "Bye"
        default:
            resultText = "No"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to assign a value to resultText inside the body of the view. This is not allowed because the body of a view must return a view, not perform actions or assign values.

Here's an updated version of your code with these changes:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012"]
    @State private var selectedYearIndex = 2
    @State private var resultText = ""
    
    var selectedYearText: String {
        switch selectedYearIndex {
        case 0:
            return "Hello"
        case 1:
            return "Hi"
        case 2:
            return "Bye"
        default:
            return "No"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Result Text:")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(selectedYearText)")
                .onReceive([self.selectedYearIndex].publisher.first()) { _ in
                    self.resultText = selectedYearText
                }
            Spacer()
            
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                ForEach(0..<years.count) {
                    Text("\(years[$0])").font(.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what’s happening in the `onReceive`? I know it is being used to initialise `resultText` and also update it if the picker changes, but I don’t understand the code that is in the `()`. Thanks.

Comment: The onReceive modifier takes two arguments: a publisher (you asking here) and a closure. In this case, the publisher is an instance of the Publisher type, created using the publisher property on the selectedYearIndex variable. The publisher property returns a publisher that emits a new value whenever the selectedYearIndex changes. The first() method is used to make sure that the closure is only called once, when the publisher emits its first value. This is because we only need to update the resultText variable once, when the user selects a new year from the picker.